# Magento 2 product video won't start because of vimeo http instead of https

Tags: magento2, video

I'm using magento 2.0.7, and I'm trying to put a video for my products. So I put the vimeo link, in https, in the url field , I save it, but when I go on the product page, it wont start because of the http, even if I've put the link in https. Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

there is a bug in magento2 v. 2.1 and still in 2.1.2.

There is a workaround:

[Bugtracking and solution](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6331)

Its not working for me but it work for some other ppl. I cant set all xml construction of my catalog_product_view in the default theme. Thats why I cant accept that i have to backstep to the default magento theme to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix:

Copy Magento_ProductVideo >web > js >load-player.js to same dir in your theme.
At line 320 in load-player.js, change http://player.vimeo.com/video/ to https://player.vimeo.com/video/

Answer (score 0):

Just cut the url. e.g.

https://player.vimeo.com/video/384708638?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0

cut it to

https://vimeo.com/384708638

Comment: Link is not I link is invalid.